# Customer Key Of The _PushTag Data View

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, data, mobilepush, data-views

Is there a customer key to the "_PushTag" data view? I need it for API uses and SSJS development.

Comment: Yes. That's actually a nice workaround. Thanks Lukas!

Comment: Don’t thank me, thank @Gortonington ;-)